# Export base class symbols in C++

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors

If you need to export class :

(1) In case of class inheritance (with "virtual") you MUST add "PUBLIC" to  "class X" definition?

(2) It is the correct way to add always "PUBLIC" to "class X" definition?

---

For example compilation of this:

myclass.h

```
#define PUBLIC  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))

class BaseClass
{
public:
    PUBLIC BaseClass();
    PUBLIC virtual ~BaseClass();
};

class SonClass : BaseClass
{
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
BaseClass::BaseClass(){}
BaseClass::~BaseClass(){}
```

mytest.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
int main()
{
    BaseClass bc;
    SonClass sc;
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CXX := g++
SOBJ := myclass.o
SLIB := myclasslib

BINOBJ := mytest.cpp
BINNAME := mytest


all: $(SOBJ) $(SLIB) $(BINNAME)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -fvisibility=hidden -c -fPIC $< -o $@

$(SLIB):
    $(CXX) -shared -o lib$(SLIB).so $(SOBJ)

$(BINNAME):
    $(CXX) $(BINOBJ) -o $@ -L. -l$(SLIB)


clean:
    -$(RM) *.so
    -$(RM) *.o
    -$(RM) $(BINNAME)
```

Failed with this linker error:

```
/tmp/ccloiGSt.o:(.rodata._ZTI8SonClass[_ZTI8SonClass]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for BaseClass'
```

---

NOTE1:

(1) If i delete the "virtual" from "~BaseClass" i'ts compiled.

(2) If i change the "class BaseClass" to "class PUBLIC BaseClass" i'ts compiled.

---

NOTE2:

I compiled it without the line "SonClass sc;" from "mytest.cpp"
, and check the symbols :

```
nm -DC libmyclasslib.so
```

The main difference between "class PUBLIC X" and "class X" is that the second missing this symbols:

```
0000000000200e00 V typeinfo for BaseClass
00000000000009b9 V typeinfo name for BaseClass
0000000000200de0 V vtable for BaseClass
```

---

NOTE3:

This problem is because of the rtti, if I cancel it (with the "-fno-rtti" flag) all will compile.

Comment: It's a good idea to add PUBLIC to the class itself. It will export all visible *and hidden* members.

Comment: "It's a good idea to add PUBLIC ..." - but i'ts MUST?